# Summation of Multiplication of two fields on Cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra, sum, aggregate, cql, nosql-aggregation

I have stats table.
stat_date, views (counter), amount (decimal)

I want to multiply fields and aggregate. It works like this in MySQL.

SELECT SUM(views * amount) FROM stats;

But not work on cassandra. Is there a function or an udf for it?

Thanks.

I created udf function for this problem. So this works great.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multiplication(input1 counter, input2 double)
CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS double
LANGUAGE java AS 'return input1 * input2;';
```

And sum all rows.

```
SELECT SUM(multiplication(views, amount)) FROM stats;
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't query like this in cassandra.**

All the aggregate function in cassandra (min, max, avg, sum, and count) function received only column name and constant as parameter, nothing else.